# Build failure: java: package org.springframework.boot does not exist

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

Was following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5PdEmeopJVQ&t=1832s

Got the following errors while running build:

[I've replace person info with <>]

```
C:\Users\<>\Desktop\Movie_App\movies\movies\src\main\java\dev\<>\movies\MoviesApplication.java:3:32
java: package org.springframework.boot does not exist

C:\Users\<>\Desktop\Movie_App\movies\movies\src\main\java\dev\<>\movies\MoviesApplication.java:4:46
java: package org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure does not exist
C:\Users\<>\Desktop\Movie_App\movies\movies\src\main\java\dev\<>\movies\MoviesApplication.java:6:2
java: cannot find symbol
  symbol: class SpringBootApplication
C:\Users\<>\Desktop\Movie_App\movies\movies\src\main\java\dev\<>\movies\MoviesApplication.java:10:9
java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable SpringApplication
  location: class dev.<>.movies.MoviesApplication
```

---

Here is my pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>dev.<></groupId>
    <artifactId>movies</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>movies</name>
    <description>A simple APIs related to movies</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

---

Things I've tried:

1. Ensuring "Target bytecode version is 17" in build,Execution,Deployment->Java Compiler -> Module.
2. I've tried reloading all maven project using the Maven side tab.
3. I've made sure the jdk being used is 17 version.

Comment: Please add your full class... Looks like you are missing imports. Another thing to try is to purge your repository `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository` which will remove the jars from the repository. Then try to build again. Also make sure that your project is imported properly as a maven project.

Comment: Thanks for the help :). Not sure what fixed it but, here's what I did:
1. Changed the project folder to another drive
2. Downloaded, installed Maven and added into environment variable and PATH.
3. Ran intellij in Admin mode.